# What does the mess attribute do?

Tags: html

I saw this on a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937077/how-can-i-do-this-on-a-larger-scale) recently.

```
<input type="radio" mess="whats up" name="q1" value="A" class="correct"/>
```

I can't get what the `mess` attribute do, and I couldn't see any result on the internet. So what is the `mess` attribute for?

Comment: There is no such attribute.

Comment: @SLaks you can see the question, I provided the link.

Comment: That question you linked to actually answers this - it's not a standard attribute, it's an approach the poster used to attach custom data to DOM elements.

Comment: @DCoder so is it possible to add any attribute you want to an html element?

Comment: [You can add custom attributes to your HTML, but unless you're using html5 and specifically allowed attribute names, it will make your document invalid](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1735268/1233508).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `mess` attribute, in the question he just used it to `attr` and get the value through JQuery.

For example:

`checked = $('input:checked').attr('mess');` sets **checked** to whatever the checked input had on the '`mess` attribute', as seen in the [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937077/how-can-i-do-this-on-a-larger-scale)

Another example:

`$('#BobDiv').attr('txt');` will return 'Bob' if your HTML is `<div id = 'BobDiv' txt = 'Bob' />`

As seen [here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735230/can-i-add-custom-attribute-to-html-tag) you have to amend it in your **!DOCTYPE**  declaration, though.

Comment: So can I add any attribute I want to do so?

Comment: @user689 Yes, basically, but you have to amend your !DOCTYPE declaration (i.e. DTD) to allow it

Comment: just for your information however still this will suffer error in w3c html5 validator `Attribute mess not allowed on element input at this point.`.

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan Yes, I agree, that's why there are better ways to do stuff like this

Answer (score 4):

It can be called as [custom attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735230/can-i-add-custom-attribute-to-html-tag) intended to store a piece of information (purely for developer puropse)but it not advisable.

Instead you can go for [**`HTML5 custom data attribute`**](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) like

```
data-mess="whats up"
```

It can be easily accessed with [**.data()**](http://api.jquery.com/data/) in jQuery.

```
<input type="radio" data-mess="whats up" name="q1" value="A" class="correct"/>
```

See

```
$('.correct').data('mess') // to getch the value
$('.correct').data('mess', 'some value')  //to update the value
```

**FYI:***`custom data-`** is purely validated with [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/check).  Whereas not with yours.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a way to store arbitrary data in the tag. It does whatever the programmer intends it to do. Some people prefer to add custom attributes via `data-foo`, others prefer this syntax.